# Prepend file location at start of file in WebStorm || Ang CLI

Tags: angular-cli, webstorm

I've grown used to the format of having the file source as the 1st line in every file, but I'm curious if there is a way to automate this.

I found the `Templates` section within WebStorm, but it doesn't have a `${PATH}` variable. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/file-template-variables.html

I looked into it a bit for Ang CLI but it seems like I would have to clone it and modify it myself which seems wrong.

Essentially I'd love for any file generated via `ng g c component` to output the first line of the file as 
`<!-- / src/app/component/component.component.ts -->`
etc, with a dynamic path.

Is this possible, or will I have to continue doing it manually, or writing a script to handle it after-the-fact?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, there are no predefined variables for file path, see [IDEA-136387](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136387). Please vote for this request in order to move it up in the queue and receive notifications regarding the progress with it. See more information on this at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135.
But modifying WebStorm file templates won't affect `ng generate` anyway...
According to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2377, the most recent cli version already supports custom blueprints for code generation; didn't try it though